# Mark pull request as ready to review

Tags: github

Draft pull requests have been available for over a year now on Github. The REST API documentation shows how to create a pull request in draft state, but not how to mark it as ready to review.

An issue on hub suggests this might work:

```
hub api -H 'accept: application/vnd.github.shadow-cat-preview+json' \
  -XPATCH repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/NUMBER -F draft=false
```

However, it did nothing when I tested it.

How can I do this through the API?

Answer (score 3):

The only API which does take "draft" as an input parameter is the "[Create a PR](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request)" one (as illustrated by [hub issue 2038](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/2038)).

The "[Update a PR](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#update-a-pull-request)" API has no `draft` parameter, which would explain why the API call did not change/updated the PR.
From what I can see, this is not yet possible through the GitHub API.

The is a [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/mutation/markpullrequestreadyforreview/) call though: "`markPullRequestReadyForReview`"

Plus, from this [Go wrapper issue](https://github.com/google/go-github/issues/1120), don't forget to  set the header to "`application/vnd.github.shadow-cat-preview+json`".

Comment: I gathered all of that. I was hoping for a more authoritative answer... :(

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Agreed. I was hoping others might chime in here.